# Is it a bad approach to loop in values from JS->PHP->mySQL?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, security, pdo

I´m still learning and trying to write my code as small and effective as possible.

So my regular approach while insert data to mySql from a HTML form is by
fetch input values with Jquery:

```
var formdata = {};
    $('.formdata').each(function(){
        formdata[ $(this).attr('name') ] = $(this).val();
});
```

Send it to PHP with Ajax:

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'file.php',
        method: 'post',
        data: {formdata: formdata},
        success: function(result){
            console.log(result)
        }
 });
```

Grab POST and put it into a array:

```
$params_array = array(
        ':artNr' => $_POST['formdata']['artNr'],
        ':etc' => $_POST['formdata']['etc'],
);
```

And finally put it into mySql:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO table SET artNr = :artNr, etc = :etc";
    try{ 
        $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
        $result = $stmt->execute($params_array);
    } 
    catch(PDOException $ex){
        die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage()); 
    }
```

My question is now:
Is it a bad approach to loop in values from POST to array?

```
foreach( $_POST['formdata'] as $name => $value ){
    $params_array[$name] = $value;
}
```

Reason for asking is that i don´t know if you are able to send stuff into my JS "formdata[]" from the console and do hacking stuff?

What i mean is that i´m looping whatever exist in the HTML form.. into my database. Without any hardcoded keys in my "params_array"..
Maby there is even more security holes that i´m not aware of?

I know PDO is pretty secure from SQL injections?!

Comment: Not PDO is secure from SQL Injections, prepared statements are. You could do the same with `mysqli_` driver, that would be secure too. I know this doesn't answer your question at all, its just a little note.

Comment: Some thoughts, you should precise which data type you expect `file.php` will return. I may advice to set your `$.ajax` property `dataType: "json"` and to return the result inside your `file.php` once you finished to process it like this : `echo json_encode( $result->fetchAll() );`

Comment: @AnwarNairi I don´t need to set the dataType to JSON to be able to return it with echo json_encode. I already do this and it works. But is it safer to use dataType?

Comment: @Twinfriends ok, thank you for clearing that out.

Comment: Unless you have a specific reason to loop over the individual form elements on the client side, you should use https://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Comment: @CBroe The reason why i like to loop everything in is because i know that the form will groove in time. So i don´t have to add code in all places later on. Also it´s smaller and nicer code. I will take a look at your link... thanks!

Comment: _“Is it a bad approach to loop in values from POST to array?”_ - that code is first and foremost a _nonsense_ approach, because you are just putting all array items found in $_POST into $params_array, so effectively you are just “cloning” $_POST as $params_array. You should work with $_POST directly instead. But in both cases you have to check what values you are actually passing on the database anyway.

Comment: _“Reason for asking is that i don´t know if you are able to send stuff into my JS "formdata[]" from the console and do hacking stuff?”_ - you would be absolutely naive of course to expect that all requests reaching your server were even send by a “browser” ... anyone can send _any_ data to your script, so you can not rely on anything, but have to check, always.

Comment: @CBroe I see what you ment about "clone" i was thinking to put in the semicolon ":" in the key.. as in the params_array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always consider user input to be (potentially) dangerous. If you expect an integer, make sure it actually is one. Validation on the client side wouldn't ensure security. I can still make a [POST request](https://www.hurl.it) to your endpoint, providing the parameters I want.

I wouldn't loop through the `formdata` array on the backend. It could break your prepared statement if the number of parameters don't add up the number of placeholders.

So, you were doing just fine:

```
$data = $_POST['formdata'];

$params = [
    ':artNr' => intval($data['artNr']),
    ':etc'   => htmlspecialchars($data['etc']),
];
```

Also, use jQuery's [serialize](https://api.jquery.com/serialize) method to encode a set of form elements as a string. It's a more efficient approach to obtain the form values.

```
var $form = $('#myForm');

$form.submit(function(event) {
    var request = $.post('https://endpoint.com', $form.serialize());

    request
        .done(function(data) {
            console.log('Done', data);
        })
        .fail(function(error) {
            console.log('Request fail', error);
        });

    event.preventDefault();
});
```

This way you wouldn't need to loop through each `.formdata` element.

Comment: Thank you. I will look into this. I´m not using a regular HTML form as i do not wan´t to reload the page. Is it possible to use .serialize on a DIV?

Comment: Don't start hacking by using a `div` for forms, simply prevent the default action from being triggered by using `e.preventDefault()`. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Why the "$" in front of var? $form

Comment: To indicate that the variable contains a jQuery object, it's a code practice I like to follow.